# Problem create resource through web-service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services

I want to let anybody to create user into my site, so I tired create some dummy user scaffold and use `curl -d "user=dummy" http://localhost:3000/users` ,but this not work. How to accomplish this kind of task.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide some details about how your UsersController#create works.
Assuming you use the basic scaffold and the user table has a `username` attribute, you are passing invalid parameters

```
curl -d "user[username]=dummy" http://localhost:3000/users
```